# AJAX JSON only loading once, when refreshing it fails (only in IE7 & 8)

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have a microsite which loads in JSON content with Ajax, it works first time in IE7 and IE8, but if I refresh those browsers it fails, I have checked in fiddler and I receive no errors. Could it be an error in the code somewhere?

```
var firstBackgroundImage = new Image();
                firstBackgroundImage.src = "img/bg-img.jpg";        
                firstBackgroundImage.onload = function () {
                    $('#loading-image').hide();
                    $(".wrap").fadeIn(300);
                    loadContent();
                };

function loadContent(){ 
    $.ajax({
        url: "json/" + language + "/content.json",
        data: "nocache=" + Math.random(),
        type: "GET",
        cache : false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(source){
            data = source;
            showStartpage(data);
            showInfo(data);
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert("Failed to load content");
        }
    }); 

}
```

The alert "Failed to load content" doesn't appear either it just shows the loading image I have in place, any possible faults there might be? Anyone ever had same problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works the first time because Internet Explorer isn't loading the image from cache, so the `load` event fires after your `firstBackgroundImage.onload = ...` line to set up the event handler. However, on subsequent page loads it is using a cached version of the image, and as a result the `load` event is firing before you've set up the event handler for it.

Simply change the order of those two lines. Set the `load` event handler and then set the `src` property of the image:

```
var firstBackgroundImage = new Image();
firstBackgroundImage.onload = function () {
    $('#loading-image').hide();
    $(".wrap").fadeIn(300);
    loadContent();
};
firstBackgroundImage.src = "img/bg-img.jpg";
```